# Ending thread either on completion or after specified time whichever occurs first in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I got some issue with Perl Threading and need your help.

I want run some task [adb execute some command] in perl. My requirement is to exit from loop / thread once the execute command completes or kill that execute task itself after specified time [say 3 hrs]. For this i am trying to have use:threads

Task 1 - Will execute some thing - may take less or more time
Task 2 - Timer for 3hrs

So it is working partially. i mean exiting from the loop once ADB task finishes but not the other way.

```
<pre>
use threads;
    my $thr = threads->create(\&sub1);   # Spawn the thread
    $thr->detach();   # Now we officially don't care any more
    my $thr = threads->create(\&sub2);   # Spawn the thread
    $thr->join();   
    #sleep_string(10);        # Let thread run for awhile
    sub sub1 {
       sleep(10800); 
    }        
    sub sub2 {
       Execute ADB task
    }        
</pre>
```

Comment: When the timeout occurs, you could send the thread a "thread signal". If you want to exit cleanly, you'd have a handler catch that signal and `die`. (This only works if the operation consists of Perl code, since "thread signals" are only checked between Perl instructions.) That's the easy part. The hard part is waiting for a thread to finish or a timer to end.

Comment: Does it have to be a thread? Because the combination of `alarm()` and `fork()` would do this quite easily.

Comment: Thanks ikegami, i will check that and let you know

Comment: Thanks Sobrique, it is not necessarily to be a thread, so can you please give some more inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on from the comments, my suggestion would be don't thread at all. This *looks* like a simple system command that you're running, and you want to kill after a timeout.

So I would approach it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

alarm 3; 
my $pid = open ( my $output_from_proc, "-|", "tail -f /var/log/messages" ); 
$SIG{'ALRM'} = sub { 
    print "Killing $pid because of timeout\n"; 
    kill 15, $pid 
    undef $SIG{'ALRM'}; #irrelevant unless you reuse alarm
};
print <$output_from_proc>; 
waitpid ( $pid, 0 );
```

`open` opens as an executable, and performs it's own fork - and returns `STDOUT` via `$output_from_proc`. You set an 'ALRM' signal handler. `alarm` requests the kernel to send you a `SIGALRM` after the designated time (it's perfectly precise, but more than adequate for a timeout).

And when your `ALRM` signal comes, the process is killed. This should work within a thread if you really want, but I'd try to avoid it.

Comment: thanks Sobrique, one doubt is if $output_from_proc finishes before ALRM / timeout - then how it will exit

Comment: When it does this, the `$output_from_proc` filehandle will close,  and you'll  get an EOF when reading it. Or you can test via `waitpid` to see if it has exited - it'll stay as a zombie until it's reaped

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply/ Thanks a lot Sobrique. it worked fine.